# What is this beautiful shrub with white and pink flowers

Tags: identification, shrubs

I have these shrubs and I want to know what kind of plant it is. It has white and pink flowers, big branches, and soft leaves.
It grows in North Carolina, United states
Pictures:
[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plant is [Glossy Abelia](https://www.google.com/search?q=glossy%20abelia&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS908US908&sxsrf=ALeKk03O9ZToZh3rMQjfrZJsKz2hb610lA:1626104103658&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjY-Nzr7d3xAhVsEVkFHcf2AfIQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1920&bih=890), and its scientific name is Abelia x grandiflora. It grows in North Carolina. It is an ornamental shrub.

History of [abelia's](https://www.arborday.org/trees/treeguide/TreeDetail.cfm?ItemID=644):

> Originally from Italy, this popular rounded shrub makes a fine hedge, barrier, mass, or foundation plant. It also works to combat erosion when planted along a bank. Graceful, arching branches are covered with white flowers tinged with rose from late summer through the fall, attracting butterflies and bees.
> The glossy abelia is a versatile, easy-to-maintain option that will add year-round interest to any landscape.

Here are the care [instructions](https://www.nature-and-garden.com/gardening/glossy-abelia.html):

> Glossy abelia is planted indifferently in fall or in spring. However, planting in fall will make regrowth easier.
> Choose a spot preferably sheltered and in full sun because glossy abelia prefers sun to bloom. When planted in the ground, it requires light, well drained and especially not-too-moist soil.
> Growing glossy abelia in a pot is possible, but you must schedule repotting every 2 or 3 years and prune often to constrain its growth.